# Plotting graphs by row within one plot with R

Tags: r, lattice, gridextra

Sample data:

```
rdata <- data.frame(y=rnorm(1000,2,2),v1=rnorm(1000,1,1),v2=rnorm(1000,3,3),
                    v3=rnorm(1000,4,4),v4=rnorm(1000,5,5))
```

This doesn't do what I need:

```
library(lattice)
library(gridExtra)    
plot1 <- lapply(1:2, function(i) {bwplot(~rdata[,i],rdata)})
plot2 <- lapply(1:3, function(i) {bwplot(~rdata[,i],rdata)})
plot3 <- lapply(1:4, function(i) {bwplot(~rdata[,i],rdata)})


print(do.call(grid.arrange, c(plot1,plot2,plot3)))
```

I would like to plot the graphs by row so that in this case the `plot1` shows up within 1 plot in first row only 2 graphs, second row 3 graphs and 3rd row 4 graphs. How to do this?

EDIT: Desired output:

[image]

Comment: `grid.arrange(do.call(arrangeGrob, c(plot1, list(nrow=1))), do.call(arrangeGrob, c(plot2, list(nrow=1))), do.call(arrangeGrob, c(plot3, list(nrow=1))))` seems to work but im sure it can be tidied up.

Comment: This works!If you're happy with submitting this as an answer, I would accept it straightaway.Thanks!

Comment: Good stuff Max. I'll wait a wee bit to see if someone answers as I expect the code can be improved on

Comment: Hmm, in fact it is not as good solution as I thought. I would like the each individual graph to be equal size. The last 4 graphs are too narrow. That means that it should plot 4 graphs equal size and the first row with the 2 graphs should be plotted as if there would be 2 invisible graphs plotted.

Comment: you can do this by forcing the number of columns with the `ncol` argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upgrade comment to answer

Not sure if this is much of an improvement from the comment but perhaps is a bit more scalable

```
# arrange list of grobs for each plot
l <- lapply(list(plot1, plot2, plot3), 
                      function(i) do.call(arrangeGrob, c(i, nrow=1, ncol=4)))

# plot
do.call(grid.arrange, l)
```

Comment: Great.This does what I need.Thanks!